# ios bitmap pixels manipulation

Tags: ios, graphics, pixmap

I want to manipulate individual pixels on iOS, high performance preferably, but I am not sure where to start looking. Any good links to docs and samples? What choices there are?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463719/iphone-app-display-pixel-data-present-in-buffer-on-screen/15464006#15464006)

Comment: Manipulate individual pixels in what way? There are many ways, but without knowing what you're trying to do, it's hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: I have a 32 bit unsigned int array of pixels and I just want then to display on UIView.